# 403 error while authenticating GraphQL API with JWT token in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, jwt, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to secure my GraphQL API with JWT, I have already implemented it with REST API, also I'm using the same base but it continues throwing 403 error. There are no logs neither error it it just throws 403.
[Error found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJZ2S.png)

In this same project I have a REST endpoint and it work correctly, but the same project but for the GrphqlAPI does not work.

I don't know if there is any different approach for this type of API.

Please help me with this.

Here is the code.

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAutheticationFilter jwtAutheticationFilter;
    private final ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authRequest ->
                authRequest
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(applicationConfig.authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAutheticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }


}
```

App Config:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(getPassEncoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(getUserDetails());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getUserDetails() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(()->new UsernameNotFoundException("Not User Found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPassEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

JWT Filter:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAutheticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = getTokenForRequest(request);
        String username;

        if(token==null){
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }

        username=jwtService.getUserNameFromToken(token);

        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()== null){
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(token,userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }

    private String getTokenForRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String token = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if(token !=null &&token.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            return token.split(" ")[1];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {

    private final ProductService productService;

    @QueryMapping
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productService.getAllProducts();
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public List<Product> getThreeMoreExpensiveProducts(){
        return productService.getThreeMoreExpensiveProducts();
    }

    @MutationMapping
    public Product saveProduct(@Argument ProductoRequest productoRequest){
        return productService.saveProduct(productoRequest);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "hello")
    public String Hello(){
        return "hello";
    }

}
```